# "Which is better" or "Which are better"?

Tags: comparison

Which one is grammatically correct?

1. "Which is better, cats or dogs?"
2. "Which are better, cats or dogs?"

If they are both ok, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

Because both cats and dogs are plural, “Which are” would be grammatically correct in this case. “Which is” would be used in a singular situation such as, “Which is better, blue or green?”

Are is used in plural present tense.

“They are”, “We are”, “The dogs are”

Is should be used for singular present tense.

“He is”, “It is”, “The dog is”, “Blue is”

In this case, your verb conjugation is tied to your nouns; “cats” and “dogs” which are both plural.

Answer (score 1):

Because both *cats* and *dogs* are plural, “Which are” would be grammatically correct in this case. “Which is” would be used in a singular situation such as  “Which is better, blue or green?”. *Are* is plural while *is* should be used for singular words.